# MOSFET LDO, how does it work

Tags: mosfet, ldo

I can't understand how MOSFET LDO works and when it would be low drop.

Below, there is a simple schematic with N channel mosfet and TL431. Providing gate voltage, D-S will open, but minimum Gate-Source voltage for eg. IRF540 is 4V (for 1A drain current). Load is connected between source and GND, so minimum Gate-GND voltage is Vout+Vgs=Vout+4V, so whole Vin is minimum Vout+4V.

Do I understand it correctly?

[image: Circuit schematic]

Comment: Using a regular NMOS for the series regulation *probably* is mutually exclusive with it being a LDO. Typical series regulation parts are PFET/PNP. This still could work as a *linear* regulator, but many people conflate/confuse the two terms.

Comment: @W5VO You are aware that an LDO regulator _is_ a linear regulator?

Comment: @marcelm And that's the exact problem that I'm talking about - so many people are used to the statement "LDO == Linear Regulator" that they assume the commutative property "Linear Regulator == LDO". Next time find a way of saying that without patronizing people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your circuit works as an LDO regulator but only because there is a 5 volt power source that can lift the gate 5 volts higher than the input supply voltage. This means that if you only need 4 volts gate-source there will be virtually a zero voltage drop-out performance.

All linear LDO regulators that I know of don't have this useful but impractical voltage source hence they use PMOSFET transistors.

Comment: Actually there are a fair number of LDOs with a bias input intended to be used with a low-current higher voltage rail to get lower dropout, so sometimes when the extra voltage source exists anyway it can help get very low dropout on another rail: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7a10.pdf

Comment: @JohnD Nice find so now I can say that I know of no regular LDO regulators and only 1 irregular LDO regulator (that requires a low current bias voltage 1.4 volts above Vin).

Comment: So only solution is to change N MOSFET to NPN BJT?
Am I able to reduce dropout using P channel and TL431 in similar configuration?

Comment: @kamillabaarnowak - no with a PMOSFET you will need an extra inversion of the signal and you get an accompanying level of instability that you have to fight against / correct in the design. Not a simple step. Anyway that question, if you are interested in a fuller answer would best be served by googling how they work and if you have issues ask a new question here.